# Qt inheriting from QGraphicsEllipseItem

Tags: qt

I was trying to inherit from QGraphicsEllipseItem 'cause i wanted to add some functionality to it. However i was faced with this error, which probably has something to do with the compiler/precompiler or moc?

```
error: 'staticMetaObject' is not a member of 'QGraphicsEllipseItem'
```

And here's the class code:

```
class MyEllipseItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyEllipseItem (const QRectF & outline) : QGraphicsEllipseItem(outline)
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QGraphicsEllipseItem is not QObject, so just remove Q_OBJECT from class declaration.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Would be nice if you could use a subclass of QGraphicsEllipseItem as a QObject as well, so you could use signals and slots with it.

Comment: You still could use composition to achieve this. Just add to your class the attribute of some type, inherited from QObject.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar error when inheriting from QRunnable which by the the way is NOT a QObject. 
**Cause**

1. [Bad order of inheritence](http://slopjong.de/2008/10/07/staticmetaobject-is-not-a-member/)

Answer (score 1):

If however you need to use some slots/signals in your class you could inherit from QObject as well like the QGraphicsObject does

```
class MyEllipseItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem, public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyEllipseItem (const QRectF & outline) : QGraphicsEllipseItem(outline)
    {

    }
};
```

It may be a better idea to inherit from `QGraphicsObject` and reimplement the ellipse drawing.

For more details check the [QGraphicsObject documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsobject.html).

Answer (score 1):

in this case you need just to try inherit the QObject  **First**, I mean:

Remember that "**Multiple Inheritance Requires QObject to Be First**", otherwise you'll get either the same error as above, or something along the lines of "YourClass inherits from two QObject subclasses" from the moc.

[See this link!](http://www.setnode.com/blog/qt-staticmetaobject-is-not-a-member-of/) for more information.

for example:

```
#include<QObject>
#include<QGraphicsEllipseItem> 
class myclass :  public QObject , public QGraphicsEllipseItem{
Q_OBJECT


// your code...

};
```